# Android kernel compilation: bus error (core dumped)

Tags: android-source

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with virtualbox and arm-eabi-4.3.3 toolchains
During compilation my android kernel, or even the one from sources I get that error:

```
   bus error (core dumped)
make *** [vmlinux] Error 135
```

any idea? something wrong with toolchains or with whole ubuntu?

Comment: give more informations ... what have you tried to do and you have these results?

Comment: This appears to be a failing during linking of the kernel.  You can get considerably more verbose debug output with `make V=1` when compiling the kernel.

Comment: I simply tried to compile kernel: export ARCH=arm, export CROSS_COMPILE=~mydirectory, make DUPA_defconfig, make menuconfig, make